# What does the bash' builtin `declare -n z` do with the `z` parameter?

Tags: bash, built-in, declare

I would love to know how bash' `declare` `-n` option works when given only a single argument.

For example:

```sh
declare -n z
echo "${z}"  # ""          (empty string as expected)
z="somevalue"
echo "${z}"  # ""          (empty string)

declare -n z
echo "${z}"  # ""          (empty string)
z="somevalue"
echo "${z}"  # somevalue   (huwh? How come z is now assigned a value?)
```

Why does it seem like the second `declare` call unsets the nameref attribute?
How come that the second assignment operation seems to *work* but the first one doesn't?

I'm using bash version `5.0.17(1)-release`

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510220? This isn't programming-specific.

Comment: @jonrshape Thank you for your moderation. I did see the link before but - to my fault - I only read the accepted answer which does not answer that question. So I think it is valuable for documentation purposes to add a link to the helpful answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510342/391074

Comment: @jonrshape. I've updated the question to be more specific and not be covered by other StackExchange questions. I hope that makes it more useful to the community.

Comment: I think this is fine; it's a question about the semantics of the `bash` scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: The first assignment fixes which variable `z` refers to. The second assignment changes the value of that variable. The second call to `declare` is essentially a no-op; you've already set the `nameref` attribute on `z`; doing so a second time changes nothing.

---

The first time you use `declare`, `z` is uninitialized and undefined. The *first* assignment to `z` (whether in the call to `declare` or subsequent to it) determines which variable `z` refers to.

```
$ declare -n z
$ echo $z

$ z=somevalue
$ declare -p z
declare -n z=somevalue
```

`echo $z` at this point produces no value because `somevalue` itself is undefined.

Your *second* call to declare doesn't really do anything to `z`:

```
$ declare -n z
$ declare -p z
declare -n z=somevalue
```

It's still a reference to the variable `somevalue`. But now your second assignment to `z` does something different: it assigns a value to the variable `somevalue`, so that now when you do `echo $z`, you see the value of the variable `somevalue`, just as if you had written `echo $somevalue`.

It's a little less confusing if we use a different value for the two assignments, so we can distinguish between the referenced variable and its value.

```
$ declare -n z
$ z=foo
$ declare -p z
declare -n z=foo
$ z=9
$ echo $foo
9
```

Comment: Great explanation because you precisely show how one can use `declare -p` to investigate what is going on. I wish my upvote would show up. Unfortunately, my reputation is not high enough yet. Thanks @chepner

Comment: I contacted Chet Ramey - a maintainer of GNU bash and GNU Readline - and he confirmed your answer.